# RAID 5 failure Ubutnu 12.04 not rebooting

Tags: software-raid, raid5, drive-failure

I have Ubuntu 12.04 setup with software RAID 5. Dmesg started to show I/O errors continuously. I thought to reboot the system and lo and behold, it got stuck on

```
GRUB ERROR Loading 21
```

I then used an Ubuntu 14.04 USB flash drive to boot and then tried to mount the partition /dev/sdb but i constantly get this error

```
/dev/sdb is already mounted or the directory /home/mnt_point is busy
```

I verified it via the following command

```
    $sudo blkid -c /dev/null -o list
device     fs_type label    mount point    UUID
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
/dev/sda1  ext4             /              ed69e0ac-a581-4eeb-a2d8-0d42d8808713
/dev/sda2  swap             <swap>         03620bd6-33f3-4f16-82ec-25aa62692cfa
/dev/sdb1  linux_raid_member  (not mounted) 2fbc2047-9b0e-07d6-1554-b32f36a2b9d0
/dev/sdc1  ext3    BOOT     (not mounted)  5e86bcb2-413d-4cf8-a215-6979d441b14a
/dev/sdc2  swap    SWAP     (not mounted)  ca9cd817-0dca-45e3-807e-587deff72b6e
/dev/sdc3  ext3    ROOT     (not mounted)  d8c4051e-afc5-4bee-9b49-108800dee10d
```

and it showed that the /dev/sdb is NOT mounted.

Here is the output of

$cat /proc/partitions

```
major minor  #blocks  name

   8        0 1953514584 sda
   8        1 1937499136 sda1
   8        2   16014336 sda2
   8       16  390711384 sdb
   8       17  390708801 sdb1
   8       32   78150744 sdc
   8       33     104391 sdc1
   8       34    6008310 sdc2
   8       35   72035460 sdc3
```

Here is the output of lsscsi

```
$lsscsi
[0:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST2000DM001-1ER1 CC25  /dev/sda 
[1:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST3400620AS      K     /dev/sdb 
[5:0:0:0]    disk    ATA      ST380815AS       C     /dev/sdc
```

$mdadm --detail --scan

reveals nothing as i removed hard drives from the failing server and put them into a new desktop. I found one hard drive to be noisy and that has failed because it is spinning crazily.

It seems the question is how to extract the data from the hard drives that didn't fail to make a new system that is equivalent to the failing system

Comment: Remember this lesson for the future:  rebooting should almost never be your first course of action.

Comment: Please provide the output of the `blkid` command you've referred to, as well as the output of `cat /proc/partition` and `lsscsi` (if installed) and `mdadm --detail --scan` (if you are using software RAID).  If you saved some of the I/O errors include those as well.

Comment: @Gene The post is updated

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/64889/how-to-mount-recover-data-on-a-disk-that-was-part-of-a-mdadm-raid-1-on-another-m

Answer (score 0):

You can not mount or extract data from individual RAID5 member drives as the data is striped across all drives. To recover any data you need to assemble the RAID5 again. But to help you we need to see more info.

Boot your Ubuntu flash drive with all RAID5 drives connected. And report back with the output of `cat /proc/mdstat` and `mdadm --examine /dev/sd[a-z]1`